# Why does "quêm" sometimes have a circumflex?

Tags: ortografia, pronomes, perguntas

I've seen *quêm* around ([Google it!](http://www.google.com/search?q=qu%C3%AAm)), but I can't find it in my dictionary (Aurélio). Is it different from *quem* in any way? Is it an obsolete/archaic spelling, or simply incorrect?

---

Estou vendo a palavra *quem* escrita com circonflexo: *quêm* (por exemplo, no [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=qu%C3%AAm)), mas não tem no meu dicionário (Aurélio). Tem alguma diferença? Seria uma ortografia obscura/arcaica ou simplesmente incorreta?

Comment: I think it's a strange error to make, considering it's more complicated to type _quêm_.

Comment: Acho que esse "quêm" tem chances de ser um equívoco na acentuação.

Comment: First hit in google: this question! :)

Comment: I have never seen "quêm" around, and I have been reading Portuguese for over half a century now. I would say that it is not an archaism (*quem* was not among the words that lost their little hats in the sixties, and if I recall correctly, my copy of the *Thesouro da Juventude*, that featured things like *phantasma*, *epocha*, *machina*, *bebé* or *elle* has it like *quem*, without the circumflex, either). I would say that it is a hypercorrection, unless it is used for laughs, like in the Facebook page "*Quêm Quêr sêr pôpulâr*".

Answer (score 6):

Vamos ver o [primeiro resultado do Google](http://www.nossalinguaportuguesa.com.br/dicionario/qu%C3%AAm/) ao buscar-se por `"quêm"` (com as aspas), que trata-se de um site de dicionário:

> No momento não dispomos do significado de quêm.
>
> Ou a grafia da palavra quêm está incorreta ou essa palavra ainda não foi adicionada ao nosso banco de dados.
>
> Você pode utilizar o nosso corretor ortográfico gratuito para verificar se a grafia da palavra quêm está correta.

Isso não parece um bom sinal, né?

Além disso, nunca vi ninguém usando a grafia "quêm". Para mim isso parece ser apenas um erro de acentuação e simplesmente **não existe**.

Comment: Just saying, but [please don't rely on Google counts](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/397/discourage-using-number-of-google-results-as-a-source), they're incredibly inaccurate.

Comment: O número de resultados só pode ser usado como comparação entre um termo e outro, mas a quantidade em si deve ser desconsiderada, até porque um responsável da Google (faz tempo que vi, não lembro) afirmou em um vídeo que são apenas números **estimados**, e não devem ser levados a sério. Sabe aquele tempo estimado de 30 segundos que acaba levando 2 horas? Então, desse jeito. E ainda não sei dizer se as comparações são mesmo confiáveis..

Comment: Ok, vocês acham que devo deixar esta resposta aqui ou é melhor deletar ela?

Comment: Olha, eu acho que poderia apagar a parte do Google e deixar o outro argumento.

Comment: Apenas apaguei a parte do Google. Sei que é uma resposta fraca, mas é melhor do que nada.

Comment: @VictorStafusa A alternativa é usar um [corpus](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_lingu%C3%ADstico) para obter números reais. Num caso, o Google mostrou `84,000 resultados`, mas seguindo ao final, só tinha 16! (Acho que a reposta fica melhor sem os resultados de Google ;)

Comment: @Earthliŋ Muitas vezes acontece isso, se for seguir as páginas se vê que não tem todos esses "milhares" que equivocadamente o Google acusa. O ruim de usar um corpus é que se quiser saber a relevância de uma palavra recentemente, muitos resultados de 100 anos ou mais ficam no meio, como acontece no corpus do Kotonoha. Não sei se em outros é melhor organizado.

Comment: Pesquisando de várias formas no Google "quêm", só aparecem resultados com "quem" ou "quêm", nunca em algum texto falando sobre isso. E ainda há alguns resultados com os dois. Então, realmente é só um erro, mesmo.

Comment: Só para confirmar: http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/qu%C3%AAm

Answer (score 1):

Acho que as pessoas que usam "quêm" acreditam que é a terceira pessoa do plural de "quem" como no caso de verbos como ter, vir (têm, vêm). Mesmo assim, quêm não existe, pois é um pronome indefinido, não um verbo.

Comment: "como no caso de outros verbos" só para esclarecer "quem" não é um verbo, é um pronome indefinido.

Comment: @JorgeB. É pronome interrogativo e portanto também não tem número. Mas acho que é uma ideia interessante. Quêm comeram meu bolo?

Comment: @Earthliŋ como? *Quem* é um pronome indefinido que quando aplicado numa frase interrogativa é um pronome interrogativo. E eu nem consigo ler de forma adequada *quêm*...

Answer (score 1):

[This 1907 book](https://books.google.com/books?id=cLcvAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=qu%C3%AAm&source=bl&ots=eX7Qhr2woF&sig=X1Dc3fDDUboyMlqn3zcU8t9yydE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB8pjczKDOAhXrzIMKHdaoCOI4FBDoAQg-MAg#v=onepage&q=qu%C3%AAm&f=false) , *A Practical Grammar of Portuguese and English*, shows "Quem" used to be spelled with the circumflex accent in the archaic Portuguese. 
I remember reading some reprints of old Disney comics in Portuguese in Brazil, dated probably as of the 1960's and 1970's, where several words would have accents like that, which weren't in use at the time I was reading them (sometime in the early 90's). Not as many as on the book below, but still a lot more than lately.
I'd be curious to find out where you're finding "quêm". If you're finding it in any modern online material, it's most likely a typo/mistake, or Spanish.
If still in doubt, please share your source.

Comment: I don't think there have been any circumflex accents in Spanish [since the 18th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex#Other_articulatory_features).

Comment: Cleberz, check whether you approve of my changes to your text. The accents in that book do not conform to the standards of the time, or any time for that matter. My hunch is that it places an accent on every word to show the main stress for the benefit of foreign learners. This [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/x.asp) finds not a single *quêm*, or *cêm*, or *bêm* from the 1300s through to the 1900s.

Comment: @Jacinto, thanks for the changes, I've approved them. Also thanks for sharing about Corpus do Português, it's a very interesting page. I tried looking for some examples of sentences using "quem" for older years but noticed a lot of that material isn't properly recognized. For instance, I've found sentences like:
"& enmendar quando errarë. que o sabha fazer assy meesmos ley. xja. quem pode fazer as leys. ENperador ou rrey pode fazer as leys sobrela gëtes do"
I wonder if it may be related to some localization of Portuguese at the time?

Comment: (cont.) The initial pages of the book linked mention that the 1907 version (7th edition) was printed in London, but the original (1852) was printed in Lisbon (Lisboa), which is why I found it relevant. If you know of how to access the image versions of the texts found in Corpus do Português please let me know.

Comment: Search a string in Google Books. Sometimes you're lucky. I've read a few books printed in the 19th century, and have never found *quêm*. But just to double check I've looked up *quêm* in Google Books. You get less than a 100 results. When you look them up, most of them turn out to be errors of character recognition (it's *quem*, but somehow Google saw something it interpreted as ^); of the handfull of genuine *quêm*, nearly all are from grammars of the type you linked, with all the funny accents.

Comment: You get funny spelling centuries ago, and you find the same word spelt differently, sometimes in the same text, just a few lines apart. But there are errors of character recognition in the Corpus too. When you see a funny ***f***, it may be an ***s*** (they wrote long ***ss*** in those days). The ë in ***errarë*** is actually an ***e*** with "~", so *errarem*.

Answer (score 0):

Confesso que nunca ouvi falar sobre a possibilidade de aplicar circunflexo em "quêm". Prefiro acreditar que houve alguma confusão com a acentuação possível do "quê", o pronome que substitui o nome, outro pronome ou uma oração nas funções de sujeito, predicativo do sujeito ou objeto (direto ou indireto) e que deve ser usado sempre com o circunflexo quando for substantivo masculino, interjeição ou nas orações interrogativas em que esteja no final da frase. Como pronome pessoal na terceira pessoa do plural isso é novidade para mim e, tenho certeza, para todos os gramáticos com os quais aprendi as normas da língua culta.